# Listview problems

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8

this is my question look

```
public class TempStore { // this is a singleton class

public static ObservableList<Filez> files= FXCollections.observableArrayList();
}
```

now in my class

```
ListView<Filez> listfiles = new ListView<>();
listfiles.setItems(TempStore.files);
listfiles.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
listfiles.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<Event>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(Event arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println(listfiles.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());

            }
        });
listfiles.setCellFactory((ListView<Filez> l) -> listup);
```

Edit -- my liscell class

```
public class Listupdater extends ListCell<Filez> {


@Override
protected void updateItem(Filez arg0, boolean arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.updateItem(arg0, arg1);
    if(arg0 != null)
    setGraphic(view(arg0));
}

@Override
public void updateIndex(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.updateIndex(arg0);        
    setGraphic(view(TempStore.files.get(arg0)));
}

@Override
public void updateSelected(boolean arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.updateSelected(arg0);
    System.out.println("update selected");
}

@Override
public void startEdit() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.startEdit();
}

Node view(Filez arg0){
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setHgap(10);
    grid.setVgap(10);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));

    try {
        System.out.print(arg0.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.print("error caught");
    }

    Label lab = new Label(arg0.getName());      
    grid.add(lab, 1, 1);

    return grid;
 }

}
```

now my problem is i don't get nothing showing up in my listview and when i click on the listview area system.out.printIn prints -1.. and my list is not empty, is always has items in it.. what am i doing wrong can some1 help me...

also to add more info, my listview is being put into one of the tabs in tabpane..
if somebody too could just explain to me how to go about the listview too i will be statisfied, all i want is to be able to put/del items in listiview programmatically, and also style the cells in the listview with nodes..thanks

Comment: Can you fix the last line of your code? And what is `listup`?

Comment: oh sorry.. listup is my listcell class object.. should i post that too sir? @James_D

Comment: Yes, please edit your question and post the code for that. Can you also explain what your handler is supposed to do? Are you really wanting to perform some action on a mouse click, or are you actually wanting to do something when the selection changes?

Comment: ohkay.yes i would like to get the clicked item in the listview to do stuff with it.. all im trying to do is have a listview with a custom node as a cell and also get the clicked item and do stuff with and probably more functions to it..i am edittin my question now @James_D

Comment: i am done editting @James_D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, for the issue of the cells not displaying, it looks like you are returning the same instance of your `ListCell` implementation for every call to the factory. You should return a new instance each time:

```
listfiles.setCellFactory(l -> new Listupdater());
```

To react to a mouse click on the list cells, I would register the mouse listener with the individual cells, instead of with the `ListView`. That way you have access to the item, instead of having to check the selection (that is a bit of a hack: you have no real guarantee the selection is set before your listener is invoked).

So:

```
public class Listupdater extends ListCell<Filez> {

    public Listupdater() {
        setOnMouseClicked(event -> 
            if (! isEmpty() ) {
                Filez f = getItem();
                System.out.println("Click on " + f);
            }
        );
    }

    // ... your methods here
}
```

Incidentally, you don't need to implement both `updateIndex()` and `updateItem()`, just `updateItem()` will do. And the remaining methods (`updateSelected()` and `startEdit()`) seem redundant as they just invoke the superclass implementation. They shouldn't break anything, but they are just redundant code.

Comment: thank you very much sir, guys like you make stackoverflow, thanks very much.THANKS once more JAMES_D..